# how to use a signal in qml file that was declarated in c++ file

Tags: c++, signals, qml, blackberry-10

i have a problem of using signals in QML.
i have created a signal in the cpp file and i want to use it in the qml file
the file **AppUI.hpp**:

```
Class ApplicationUI: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(bool loading READ loading NOTIFY loadingChanged)
public:
    Q_SIGNALS:
    void loadingChanged();
private:
bool _loading;
bool loading() const;
...
}
```

in the file **AppUI.cpp**:

```
ApplicationUI::ApplicationUI(bb::cascades::Application *app) :
        QObject(app),_loading(false) {
...
traitment
_loading=false;
emit lodingChanged();
}

bool AppnUI::loading() const{

    return _loading;
}
```

and in **QML file**:

```
MapView {
            id: mapview
            objectName: "mapViewObj"
            visible: !_mapViewTest.loading
         }
ActivityIndicator {

            visible: _mapViewTest.loading
            running: _mapViewTest.loading
        }
```

but the problem here is that i get this ERROR on the console
*Error: NOTIFY signal 'loadingChanged' of property 'loading' does not exist in class ApplicationUI.*

Comment: The only mistake I can see so far is "emit lodingChanged();" is spelt wrong.  Is the console error you are getting indicating an issue in c++ or qml?

Comment: thank you for the response . i corrected the spelling and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

First, in c++, in order for your data member loading to be visible to QML, you first need to create a public getter, and put it into qproperty like follows:

```
Q_PROPERTY(bool getloading READ getloading NOTIFY loadingChanged)

public bool getloading() const;
```

This is because QML cannot access private member in c++ class.

Also, in QML, you can use a signal in c++ like so:

```
onCreationCompleted: { // or other function
    _mapViewTest.lodingChanged.connect(whatyouwanttodo);
}

function whatyouwanttodo() {
    // do something
}
```

Note that your signal and function connected need to have the same param list